# HTML - word full width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to fit the size of a word (variable) to full width (of a div element)?

Described at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQ3sQ/2/

ofc

```
font-size:100%;
```

won't work - maybe a hack solution?

Comment: Just use [FitText](http://fittextjs.com) - here's a working example using your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQ3sQ/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using just CSS, but you can use a Javascript library like [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/). It will measure the text and adjust it until it fits.

Comment: this is what i searched for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jquery snippet :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/DPRr9/)**

It calculates the letter-spacing to apply so the text and stretches it to 100% of the width of the container.

```
$.fn.strech_text = function(){
    var elmt          = $(this),
        cont_width    = elmt.width(),
        txt           = elmt.html(),
        one_line      = $('<span class="stretch_it">' + txt + '</span>'),
        nb_char       = elmt.text().length,
        spacing       = cont_width/nb_char,
        txt_width;

    elmt.html(one_line);
    txt_width = one_line.width();

    if (txt_width < cont_width){
        var  char_width     = txt_width/nb_char,
             ltr_spacing    = spacing - char_width + (spacing - char_width)/nb_char ; 

        one_line.css({'letter-spacing': ltr_spacing});
    } else {
        one_line.contents().unwrap();
        elmt.addClass('justify');
    }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.stretch').each(function(){
        $(this).strech_text();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`vw` units could be an hint too.

But it will adjust fom window's width, **not** from length of text within a width. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HQ3sQ/5/)**

So, if length of text and container's width is known , as in demo, it can be adjust once, with a fair `px` unit as fallback for older browser.

Notice that Chrome doesn't update properly these units on window's rezize.